# How to add additional parameter in file upload method and get on controller side?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

File add some parameter :

```
angular.forEach(files, function (file) {
    file.DocumentType = xxxxxx;
    file.userDetails = xxxxxxxxxxxxx;
    this.uploadedIdFiles.push(file);
}.bind(this));
```

service side code :

```
function FileUpload() {
    return $http({
        method: 'Post',
        url: urlconfig.resourceserviceuri + '*FileUpload*',
        data: { file: this.uploadedIdFiles }
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response;
    }).catch(function (response) {
        return response;
    });
};
```

How get the controller side for particular parameter on **DocumentType**  and **userDetails**

Comment: The browser [XHR.send](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) method can't send a file as a property of JavaScript Object. Figure out how to upload files before trying to upload additional properties.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to add additional information with a file upload:

1. Add headers
2. Add URL parameters

```js
function fileUpload(file) {
    var headers = { 'Content-Type': file.type };
    var params = { 'userDetails': JSON.stringify(file.userDetails) };
    var config = { headers, params };
    return $http.post(url, file, config); 
}
```

Comment: I am adding multiple file in upload method. how to add in param and header